# JerseyTest missing dependency com.google.common.collect.Sets

Tags: rest, maven, testing, jersey

I'm trying to test some services on an RESTful application, but I can't find out what dependency I'm missing to get JerseyTest to execute properly. I'm using maven so the POM file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>PizzaApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>PizzaApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test API ======================================== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>OSGEO GeoTools repo</id>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Hibernate Spatial repo</id>
            <url>http://www.hibernatespatial.org/repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>PizzaApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I'm deploying the application with glassfish and using postgresql trought hibernate with a spatial extension. If I deploy the application, everything works fine, only the tests I can't run.

-- Edit --

A simple test class is as follows:

```
public class PizzeriaServiceControllerTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        ResourceConfig resource = new ResourceConfig(PizzeriaController.class);
        return resource;
    }

    @Test
    public void testAll() throws Exception {
       String pizzarias = target("pizzeria/all").request().get(String.class);
       assertEquals("[]", pizzarias);
    }
}
```

The error that I get when running the tests is the following:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Application;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/utilities/Binder;)V
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.<init>(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer.<init>(GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer.<init>(GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.create(GrizzlyTestContainerFactory.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.createTestContainer(JerseyTest.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.setUp(JerseyTest.java:609)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you getting class not found when trying to run the JerseyTest class? Can you post a sample Unit test?

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw I edited the question with the request information

Answer (score 2):

The best way to see what dependencies are required in your hierarchy is to run `mvn dependency:tree`. This will list out the dependencies that are required for your project. This is also available in eclipse with the pom editor. You should have a dependency on google-collections. You can track down which package has this dependency. I bet the it is required by jersey-guava. If you don't need it you can remove it.

Alternatively you can add the google-collections.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I was using the dependency jersey-guava. I changed to guava from com.google version 18.0. That solved a missing class error but I still have problems to run the test. I added the error to the question.